# Testing DSbulk with a cassandra community

Tags: cassandra, migration

I want to migrate data. I use cassandra 3.11 and I want to compare Bulk with DS Bulk.
My problem is that when I use DS Bulk with cassandra community i have the follow error :

```
Incompatible cluster detected. Load functionality is only compatible with a DSE cluster.
The following nodes do not appear to be running DSE:
/127.0.0.1:9042
Operation LOAD_20190929-193810-582581 failed: Unable to load data to non DSE cluster.
```

Answer (score 1):

DS Bulk is a proprietary tool built to work with their proprietary database. It's likely that the tool requires features not in Apache Cassandra or simply doesn't allow being run against it.